# How to change text in animated movieClip (AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

In stage I declare `var monkey_mc:monkey=new monkey();`
**monkey_mc** is composed by 5 frames，each frames has a image and a Dynamic textfield,
textfield's name is **name**.
I add `monkey_mc.name.text = "AMY";` in my code, But when I execute, the **"AMY"** is Fleeting!
I hope the text don't disappear.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to update the "name.text" in every frame

you can do it in "onEnterFrame"

Comment: (like this?)monkey_mc.onEnterFrame = function () {
  monkey_mc.name.text = "AMY";
};

Comment: yes, this way or really a function with a proper name

Comment: I Converted textfield to components，`monkey_mc.onEnterFrame = function () { monkey_mc.name.text = "AMY"; };` dose not work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the text to be different on each frame or do you want a textfield you can edit on each one ?
What you could do is have a different layer with a textfield (with an instance name like "name" you said was to be used). That way, you can access it with getChildByName("name") in your class.

Exemple:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class monkey extends MovieClip{

private var myTextfield:TextField;

public function monkey(){
    myTextfield = getChildByName("name");
    myTextfield.text = "Amy";
    }

}
```

You can then access it in other methods of your class or, if you want you can add a getter method or put the textfield var as public to access it directly with monkey_mc.myText